# Hibernate java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, web-applications

I am running a web application with hibernate and got stuck at this exception.

```
    ... 34 more
18:50:02,573 WARN  [AbstractExceptionHandler] Unhandled exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.package.util.HibernateUtil
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:295)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170).......
```

Comment: give the whole stacktrace, and the HibernateUtil class code

Comment: Yeah, and check your static code/static field initializers in the com.package.sit.util.HibernateUtil - that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to load the definition of `com.package.sit.util.HibernateUtil` class but can't find the definition of that class.

This kind of error is usually related to class loading issues that prevents a *JAR* being loaded. Check if you have all required libraries in the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: Problem solved. I am using DB2 database and JBoss server for my application. DB2 drivers were missing in server.

Answer (score 0):

first try to add these .jar slf4j-api.jar and slf4j-log4j12.jar
because hibernate internally use these jar.

if it is not working then

follow these step for netbeans

Step 1.
delete project from the netbean but not the original file(Dont check the box which is asking for deleting the project from original location) 
Step 2.
delete dist and build folder form your project folder
step 3.
create new project with existing source code.
step 4.
add the required libraries.
now built again.
now run.

i checked it for my project it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same exact error (and misleading/useless stack trace) only to discover the solution was very simple:

Copy `ojdbc14.jar` to `%CATALINA_HOME%\lib`.

This breakthrough discovery was made possible thanks to this [Using Hibernate with Tomcat](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingHibernateWithTomcat?_sscc=t) article.

But... if I were more focused, I would have looked way higher at the very beginning of the log:

```
Jan 14, 2013 07:29:17 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
SEVERE: JDBC Driver class not found: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Moral of the story: Sometimes it pays *not* to look *only* at the point where the exception occurs but rather much much earlier in the log.